# Json toString output for "/"

Tags: java, escaping, json-simple

I get a JSON response, which I parse.
Then populate in a POJO.
Do some work on it and finally sysops json.toString instead of printing the content of the POJO.
I am using json.toString() and in the response I get
"currentTime":"08\/12\/2020 02:07:31 PM PDT"
which is basically using \ for escaping /
but for the final output I dont want this on the console.
I can only use Json simple library.

Comment: This is a [long-standing issue with the json-simple library](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/issues/8). If you must use this library, and cannot tolerate the unnecessary backslashes, you'll need to fix the output yourself. Don't just blindly replace `\/` with `/` -- be sure to test inputs like `\\/` (which should be parsed as `\/`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to replace those '/' with ' ' (space). Then you would have a reformatted string. ‍✌

Or replace it with whatever you just want.